# google drive api v3 update description

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

google drive api v3

I need to change the description of an existing object. How do I change just that, leaving the rest unchanged?

I am doing by analogy with python. I get the file metadata, add the "description" line to it and execute update. There are no errors, the description simply does not change

I don't know much about js, I will be glad if you can help me.

thanks

```js
function updateFile(fileId) {

  var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
    'fileId': fileId
  });
  request.execute(function(resp) {
    var data = resp;
    //data = data['result']
    data['description'] = "433434"
  });

  var fileMetadata = data;

  const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
  const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
  const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsBinaryString(fileData);
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var contentType = fileData.type || 'application/octet-stream';
    // Updating the metadata is optional and you can instead use the value from drive.files.get.
    var base64Data = btoa(reader.result);
    var multipartRequestBody =
      delimiter +
      'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
      JSON.stringify(fileMetadata) +
      delimiter +
      'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
      'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
      '\r\n' +
      base64Data +
      close_delim;

    var request = gapi.client.request({
      'path': '/upload/drive/v3/files/' + fileId,
      'method': 'PATCH',
      'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart', 'alt': 'json'},
      'headers': {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary + '"'
      },
      'body': multipartRequestBody
    });
    if (!callback) {
      callback = function(file) {
        console.log(file)
      };
    }
    request.execute(callback);
  };
}
```

Comment: What is your current issue?

Comment: The thing is, I don't understand how to do it. I implemented it in pyton, but it turned out that python is not suitable for my task. and js I know very badly

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't understand about the current issue of your script. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: I just don't know how to do it due to poor js skill

Comment: Just a guess, you might want to tell FileReader how to read the file before you read it, i.e. put the `reader.onload` before `reader.readAsBinaryString`.   Also, `fileMetadata` is probably undefined because where you use `data` above is limited to the local function scope.  Perhaps reviewing and extending the [Drive API quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js), slowly changing it until it's working how you expect, might help with the JavaScript understanding.

Comment: @dwmorrin
Thank you all, I figured out my problem. The code wrote in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, I figured out my problem. Here is the code, it works for me)

```
function updateFile(fileId) {
    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
      'fileId': fileId
    });
    request.execute(function(resp) {
      fileMetadata = resp;
      fileMetadata['description'] = "new_description";
      delete fileMetadata.id;
      var request = gapi.client.request({
        'path': '/drive/v3/files/' + fileId,
        'method': 'PATCH',
        'body': fileMetadata});
      request.execute(function(resp) {
      });
    })
  }
```