# Can't find files uploaded to Google Drive using REST API

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-drive-api, google-cloud-functions, expo

I'm trying to upload media files to Google Drive using the REST API and service account. I have a Cloud Functions backend where I authenticate with the right scopes for Google DRIVE API and return the access token (shown in the snippet below) to the client which could then make an upload request to Google Drive.

```
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    scopes: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    ]
});

const client = await auth.getClient();
return await client.getAccessToken();
```

This works fine on the web as seen [here](https://app-takeoff-dev.web.app/) and even on expo-snack-web as seen [here](https://snack.expo.io/@nwaughachukwuma/react-native-to-google-drive-upload). Now, I need to get this to work on the mobile platform, using React Native, but every time I upload a file, I get a 200 response and the file id, but I don't find the file on the specified folder or anywhere else on Google Drive. The snippet below is just a rewrite of the same logic I'm using to upload on the web version.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Platform, Button, Image} from 'react-native'
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import axios from 'axios'
import {decode as atob} from 'base-64'

export const UploadToDrive = (props) => {

  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [uploadPercent, setUploadPercent] = useState(0)
  const [mimeType, setMimeType] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
        const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestCameraRollPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') {
          alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
        }
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  const pickImage = async () => {
    const baseURL = 'https://dummy-server-address/api';

    // Simultaneously get the access token while picking the media
    const [{response}, result] = await Promise.all([
      fetch(
        `${baseURL}/services/fetch-access-token`,
        {
          mode: "cors",
        }
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((resp) => resp)
        .catch((err) => console.log(err)),

      ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [4, 3],
        quality: 1,
      })
    ]).catch((err) => console.log(err))

    // ensure that all needed parameters/fields are present
    if (!result.cancelled && response.token) {
      const accessToken = response.token

      const uri =  "file:///" + result.uri.split("file:/").join("");
      setImage(uri);

      const file = result
 
      let filename = uri.split('/').pop();
      let match = /\.(\w+)$/.exec(filename);
      let type = match ? `image/${match[1]}` : `image`;

      file.name = filename;
      file.type = type
      file.uri = uri
      console.log(file)

      setMimeType(file.type)
      // Upload the image using the fetch and FormData APIs
      let formData = new FormData();

      const metadata = {
        name: file.name, 
        type: file.type || 'multipart/form-data',
        parents: ["1yz6MUU0YfXz0rl7TObq-JOPCmC6sHKdQ"],
      };
     // construct the file metadata for the upload
     formData.append(
        "metadata",
        new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], { type: "application/json" })
      );

      //  formData.append('file', { uri, name: filename, type });
      formData.append('file', file);
      const url =
        "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&fields=id";

      // let uploadPercent;
      const upload_res = await axios(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { 
          Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
        },
        data: formData,
        onUploadProgress: (p) => {
          setUploadPercent((p.loaded / p.total) * 100)
        },
      })
      .catch(err => console.log({err}))
      .finally(() => setUploadPercent(0));

      console.log({ data: upload_res.data });

    } else {
      throw new Error('You do not have all the right variables to make an upload')
    }
  };

  return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>

        {!!uploadPercent && <Text style={styles.uploadPercent}>Upload Percent: {`${uploadPercent.toFixed(2)}%`}</Text>}

        <Button style={styles.button} title="Pick a file" onPress={pickImage} />
        {image && mimeType.includes('image') && <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200, marginTop: 20 }} />}
    </View>
  )
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '10%'
  },
  uploadPercent: {
    color: 'tomato',
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 20
  }
})
```

Please, what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: How do you authenticate? If the Drive is successfully uploaded, but is not on your Drive  - most liekly you are using a service acocunt that uploads the file to its own Drive.

Comment: Thanks for the response @ziganotschka. I authenticate on the Cloud Function backend and pass the access token to the client to use in the upload request. 

And yes, I understand that the service account is like any other user with its own drive. That's why I have a parent folder id which is shared with the service account so that uploads to the folder is available to me. Also, remember how I said it works on the web and on expo-snack for web

Comment: Do a files.list and you will see the files. They are being uploaded to the service accounts drive account.

Comment: Thanks, @DaImTo. But why is this happening on mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you [upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) with the service account files to a Drive that is not his, you need to set the parameter `supportsAllDrives` to `true`
- Alternatively, use [domain-wide delegation with impersonation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority) to make the service account upload files on your behalf - in this case you do not need to share your folder with the service account.

Comment: Thanks again for the desire to help @ziganotschka. So I just followed the alternative approach (point 2) to create domain wide delegation for the service account, yet I still can't upload files from a mobile environment.

I'll like to wait a little while more since it takes from minutes to 24 hours to completely propagate. But how's it that I can upload without issues on the web and expo-snack for web and not from a mobile environment? Also, how/where do I add the `supportsAllDrives ` in the API request?

Comment: I am sorry - I do not work with mobile environment. But as for `supportsAllDrives`, you can append the parameter to the URL:  `"https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?supportsAllDrives=true&uploadType=multipart&fields=id"`

Comment: As for the impersonation make sure to follow all necessary steps: Enable domain-wide delegation for the service account in the developers console AND provide the service account the necessary delegaiton scopes in the Admin console under `Security > API Controls`,  plus implement the impersonation into your code.

Comment: I have tried all of this but still don't find the files when I make an upload from a mobile environment.

Hmm, what have I not tried

Comment: I think the problem is that the metadata is not being captured on mobile. I've gotten this to work by running an update request immediately after the file upload, so I can see the file in the specified folder but it doesn't have a name. This is true for all files on the service account drive uploaded using the same approach on mobile, while the web uploads have file names or title.

Comment: I am glad you found a workaround! When you perform a file update request, you can explicitly specify the file name as sort of the request body.

Comment: Awesome following-up. Please, how do I construct that? 

I tried `body: JSON.stringify({title: filename})` but it didn't work (it threw error)

Comment: Not sure how you perform the rest of your update request so far. Have a look at those two JS samples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63430882/google-drive-api-v3-update-description https://stackoverflow.com/a/41511775/11599789

Comment: @ChukwumaNwaugha what fields do you update on? I have a similar issue where the file is being created but it's invsibile and I try to run an update on the name of the file, and says it was successful but the file doesn't appear. Very confusing

Comment: ah nvm -- turns out I was somehow uploading it to app data folder so that's why it was invisible.

Comment: Hi @howard, I'll assume you fixed it. But what I did was to first upload the file to the service account drive then run an update function to change the parent folder to the desired folder on my drive.

Comment: const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/${fileId}?uploadType=multipart&addParents=${parents}`;

     // construct the metadata using multipart/related
      const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
      const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
      const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

      const multipartRequestBody =
          delimiter +
          'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
          JSON.stringify(metadata) +
          close_delim;
  }

Comment: thanks! last night I got it to work with exactly that method. I don't think multipart/form-data or even multipart/related works with blobs (even encoded to a 64 bit string) works well.in expo :). I basically just fooled around in postman until I got things working. I also was able to rename my file if you still need help with that but looking at your code I think you are good-- for me I had to realize that my body needed to be json.stringify'd in my update haha.

Answer (score 0):

Remember a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) is not you.  A service account has its own Google drive account.  If you do a [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) and you will see the files. They are being uploaded to the service accounts drive account.

If you want them uploaded to your own google drive account then you could take the service accounts email address and share a folder on your personal drive account and grant it access to upload to that folder.   Just remember to have the service account grant your personal account [access](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing) to the files or you wont be able to access them as the service account will be owner as it uploaded the file.

If you have a gsuite account then you could set upl [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#perform_domain-wide_delegation_of_authority) and allow the service account to impersonate a user on the domain and upload them on behalf of that user meaning there will be no more issue with permissions.

## metadata name issue

Your metadata should include the name of the file you are uploading, it doesnt have to if you dont then it will be uploaded with untitled as its name.  You should be passing the metadata variable this appears to be passing a metadata string.

```
formData.append(
    "metadata",
    new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], { type: "application/json" })
  );
```

Comment: These points were already addressed in another answer, I don't see how this adds to what has already been stated in the answer and comments above

Comment: @DalmTo, I think the problem is that the metadata is not being captured on mobile. I've gotten this to work by running an update request immediately after the file upload, so I can see the file in the specified folder but it doesn't have a name. This is true for all files on the service account drive uploaded using the same approach on mobile, while the web uploads have file names or title.

Comment: The file doesn't have a name because you have not set the meta data of the file properly before uploading it.  Check my edit for a possible issue with your code.